# How to find the "variance" when using "central limit theorem" on a Poisson distribution?

Tags: poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Assume we have N number of inventors in a company. 
Inventor i expects to invent X_*i* number of inventions per year.

How many inventions each of them invent per year has a "Poisson distribution" where λ = 6 for each inventor. And we assume how many inventions each invent is independent from each other. Also one inventor inventing a lot of inventions doesn't cause any other inventor to invent more or less. Also X_*1* is independent from X_*2*.

That means for inventor number i, the number of inventions he have per year is: E(X_i) where X_i has a poisson distribution.

X is the number of total inventions made in a year. X_*i* is the total inventions made by one inventor *i* this year.

Since it's Poisson distribution, we know that E(X_*i*) =  λ  and Var(X_*i*) =  λ

And λ for each inventor is 6, so we know that E(X_*1*) = E(X_*i*) = λ

For each invention, they make 100,000 USD divided by number of inventors.

Also if there are N number of inventors in the company, and totally invented 15 inventions this year, then each of the inventor makes (15*100,000)/N. Also they share the total income equally.

The income Y for each inventor is: [image: ![enter image description here]

When N is very large, we can use central limit theorem and use Normal distribution Y~N(mean, SD)

The mean is calculated this way: 
[image]

Variance is calculated this way:
[image]

But in the text book, the answer is given as:
Variance:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Why?

What's the correct answer? How do I calculate the Variance Var(Y)?

Comment: Is this self-study or for a course? If so please add the `self-study` tag and read the associated [information](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) on how such questions are handled here. Are you aware of the relation between the mean and the variance in a Poisson distribution?

Comment: @EdM It's for a course. As I know, In Poisson distribution, mean = variance = lambda.

Answer (score 1):

**Clues:**

For the $i$th inventor, the number of inventions is $X_i \sim \mathsf{Pois}(6).$

The sum of Poisson random variables is Poisson, so
for $N$ inventors, the number of inventions is 
$S = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \sim \mathsf{Pois}(6N),$ with
$E(S) = 6N, Var(S) = 6N.$ For $N$ sufficiently large, $S$ is approximately normal.

If the dollar profit for each invention is $D,$ then
the random variable $Y = DS$ has $E(Y) = E(DS) = DE(S) = 6DN.$ What is $Var(Y)?$ From your notation, I am not exactly sure of the value of $D.$ Whatever it is,
 a multiple of an (approximately) normal random variable is also normal.

*Note:* According to your class notes or textbook, you should supply
reasons for each step.

**Simulation:** For $N = 10,$ the following simulation
in R of many such companies simulates the distribution of $S.$

```
set.seed(420)
n = 10;  lam = 6
s = replicate(10^6, sum(rpois(n,lam)))
mean(s);  var(s)
[1] 59.98709  # aprx E(S) = 60
[1] 60.06938  # aprx Var(S) = 60
```

The figure below shows a histogram of the simulated
distribution of $S.$ The centers of the small red circles atop the histogram
bars show the exact Poisson probability of each value of $S.$ The black curve is the density function of
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 60, \sigma=\sqrt{60}),$ which matches the histogram pretty well, but not perfectly. (The normal density is symmetrical about $\mu = 60,$ but
the Poisson distribution is slightly skewed to the right.)

[image]

Comment: thank you for your time. But because of my unclear writing, you misunderstood my question. I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: My answer is in terms of $S,$ not $Y.$ Partly because this is not a 'do my homework' site and partly because your original definition of $Y$ was unclear. I intended to give you a start, but not to give an answer in terms of $Y.$ // In general, if $S$ is a random variable, and $a$ is a constant, it seems you need finish this $Var(aS) = \dots$ --- in terms of $Var(S).$